# Flutter attach issue

Tags: android, flutter

I've added flutter to my existing Android, the main issue is if I made any changes first I have to run the flutter module then run the Android Module.then only I can see the changes.

to solve this we can attach flutter module using

```
$flutter attach
```

gradle classpath:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
```

When I hot reload by pressing `R`
my app crashes with following logs

```
03-13 20:11:26.367 2990-14819/? E/InputManager-JNI: sysfs_write : Error opening /sys/class/input/event14/device/enabled: 0 03-13 20:11:26.547 2990-4746/? E/MotionRecognitionService:  handler : SCREEN_OFF end  03-13 20:11:26.712 2990-3012/? E/GpsLocationProvider: sExerciseIterface is not available 03-13 20:11:27.822 2990-6918/? E/AppWidgetServiceImpl: error in getAllWidgets
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.appwidget.AppWidgetProviderInfo com.android.server.appwidget.AppWidgetServiceImpl$Provider.info' on a null object reference
        at com.android.server.appwidget.AppWidgetServiceImpl.getAllWidgets(AppWidgetServiceImpl.java:2078)
        at a.Q.getAllWidgets(Unknown Source)
        at a.c.c(Unknown Source)
        at a.c.e(Unknown Source)
        at a.B.D(Unknown Source)
        at a.B.c(Unknown Source)
        at a.D.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 03-13 20:11:30.442 2990-14874/? E/InputManager-JNI: sysfs_write : Error opening /sys/class/input/event14/device/enabled: 1 03-13 20:11:30.482 2990-4768/? E/native: do suspend false 03-13 20:11:30.497 2990-3012/? E/GpsLocationProvider: sExerciseIterface is not available 03-13 20:11:34.562 14643-14774/com.manash.purplle E/DartVM: ../../third_party/dart/runtime/vm/object.h: 8736: error: Handle check failed: saw Instance of 'HomePage' expected Closure
```

Comment: `"I am adding flutter to my existing Android"` what does it mean? what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: In existing native app I have added the flutter module

Comment: like [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps) or what?

Comment: Yes the same,,,,

Comment: so because this is **in preview** add more information about it in your question, otherwise nobody will know what you are asking about...

Comment: what more info I need to add